# How can I dispatch URLs in the form sitename.com/<slug>/<slug> in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to create a website whose structure is something like this:

A main page with various links of similar kind (like a blog). User can click on any on those and go inside any of them (link will be like site.com/slug). Then again the same thing (this time the link will be like site.com/slug/slug).

individual_question.html

```
 <div id="argument_container">
          {% for argument in argument%}
            <h6 id='{{ argument.argument_faction }}' style="display:none"><a href=" {{question.get_absolute_url}}{{argument.get_absolute_url}} " style="text-decoration: none; color: black">{{ argument.argument_text }}</a>
            <br><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" style="padding-right: 3px;"></i>Agree</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="padding-right: 3px;"></i>Disagree and debate</button>
            </h6>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', home_screen_view, name="home"),
path('register/', registration_view, name="register"),
path('logout/', logout_view, name="logout"),
path('login/', login_view, name="login"),
path('account/', account_view, name="account"),
path('<slug:question>', individual_question_view, name="individual_question_view"),

# for testing
path('<slug:argument>', individual_argument_view, name="individual_argument_view"),
```

models.py

```
    class Faction(models.Model):
    faction_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    faction_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    faction_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.faction_name

class FactionArgument(models.Model):
    argument_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    argument_faction = models.ForeignKey(Faction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    argument_question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    argument_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, null=True)
    argument_text = models.TextField()
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('individual_argument_view', args=[self.argument_slug])  # chances of error

    def __str__(self):
        return self.argument_text
```

views.py

```
    def individual_question_view(request, question):
    context={}

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, question_slug=question)
    context["question"] = question
    
    factions = Faction.objects.filter(faction_question = Question.objects.filter(question = question.question).first())
    context["faction"] = factions

    arguments = FactionArgument.objects.filter(argument_question = Question.objects.filter(question = question.question).first())
    context["argument"] = arguments

    return render(request, "snippets/individual_question.html", context)


# for testing


def individual_argument_view(request, argument):
    return render(request, "snippets/individual_chain.html")
```

I am able to get to the (site.com/slug) but not able to figure out the url dispatching for next step (site.com/slug/slug).

Currently it shows this error:

```
 Page not found (404) Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/question_1/blue2 Using the URLconf defined in Version2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/ [name='home'] register/ [name='register'] logout/ [name='logout'] login/ [name='login'] account/ [name='account'] <slug:question> [name='individual_question_view'] <slug:argument> [name='individual_argument_view'] password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done'] password_change/ [name='password_change'] password_reset/done/ [name='password_reset_done'] reset/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='password_reset_confirm'] password_reset/ [name='password_reset'] reset/done/ [name='password_reset_complete'] The current path, question_1/blue2, didn’t match any of these.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the endpoint signature in the `urls.py` file.
Right now it reads

```py
path('<slug:question>', individual_question_view, name="individual_question_view"),
```

but this covers only one slug.

```
path('<slug:question>/<slug:param2>', individual_question_view, name="individual_question_view"),
```

This will pass 2 params to the view.

Next, the `href` param in the template does not work as is due to concatenation of two separate urls instead of one with two params:

```html
href=" {{question.get_absolute_url}}{{argument.get_absolute_url}} "
```

it should be instead:

```html
href="{% url 'individual_question_view' question.question_slug argument.argument_slug %}"
```

As a side note, the `urls.py` posted has a duplicate signature, in effect the second one will not do anything because the first one will catch it and stop searching:

```py
path('<slug:question>', individual_question_view, name="individual_question_view"),

# for testing
path('<slug:argument>', individual_argument_view, name="individual_argument_view"),
```

Updated: follow-up issue discussed in answer comments.

Comment: I tried to pass 2 params to the view in the same way you suggested but it starts showing different type of error.              NoReverseMatch at /question_1
Reverse for 'individual_argument_view' with arguments '('blue2',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<question>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<argument>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Comment: that would happen if only one param ("blue2") is passed when it needs 2, I see this part in your template `<a href=" {{question.get_absolute_url}}{{argument.get_absolute_url}} "` Each of those would try to make its own independent url, it should show something weird if you check the html. Can you try this instead? `{% url 'individual_question_view' 'question1' 'blue2' %}` it should make a valid url that will use those params

Comment: Its working when I use '{% url 'individual_question_view' 'question1' 'blue2' %}' but I am trying to do it automatically so that it can change according to the content of the current page. That is why I was using '{{question.get_absolute_url}}'. It is a function inside FactionArgument in models.py which returns a reverse slug. 'def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('individual_argument_view', args=[self.argument_slug])'

Comment: When I try to do this: {% url 'individual_question_view' {{question.get_absolute_url}} {{argument.get_absolute_url}} %}, it shows Could not parse the remainder: '{{question.get_absolute_url}}' from '{{question.get_absolute_url}}'

Comment: I don't think you can nest tags like that in general. try `{% url 'individual_question_view' question.slug argument.slug %}` ("slug" here is my assumption since I don't see the Question and Argument models, otherwise you can use any attribute hereyou can normally reach with {{}})

Comment: possibly `{% url 'individual_question_view' question.question_slug argument.argument_slug %}`, going by your previous comment's feedback

Comment: Yes, now it is working perfectly using {% url 'individual_question_view' question.question_slug argument.argument_slug %}. Thank you for being patient.

Comment: Great to hear! I've updated the answer with the second issue